# How can I view Waveform Seekbar in chat?

Tags: java

[I want to add this shape I want to add this shape (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLOQz.png)

I didn't know how to deal with a library I didn't know how to deal with a waveformSeekBar library.

I hope someone helps me achieve this....

[Library link](https://github.com/artsmvch/WaveformSeekBar)

I use this code to fetch the voice message and format it with  seekbar.

`java`

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 |
| cell 3 | cell 4 |

````
audioUrl = _listmap.get((int)_position).get("audio_url").toString();


audio = new MediaPlayer();


try {


    audio.setDataSource(audioUrl);


    audio.prepare();


    audio.start();


    _seekbar.setMax((int)audio.getDuration());


    _img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (audio.isPlaying()) {


                audio.pause();


            }


            else {


                audio.start();


            }


        }});


    try {


        audiotimer.cancel();


    } catch(Exception e) {}


    try {


        audiotimer.cancel();


    } catch(Exception e) {}


    audiotimer = new TimerTask() {

        @Override

        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override

                public void run() {

                    _seekbar.setProgress((int)audio.getCurrentPosition());


                    if (audio.isPlaying()) {


                        _img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white);


                    }


                    else {


                        _img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white);


                    }

                }

            });

        }

    };

    _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(audiotimer, (int)(0), (int)(750));


} catch(Exception e) {}


_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


                @Override


                public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar _param1, int _param2, boolean _param3) {


                        final int _progressValue = _param2;


                        


                }


                


                @Override


                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar _param1) {


                        


                }


                


                @Override


                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar _param2) {


                        


        try {


            if (!audio.isPlaying()) {


                audio.start();


            }


            audio.seekTo((int)(_seekbar.getProgress()));


        } catch(Exception e) {}


    }


        });


_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white);


audio.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {


        _img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white);


    }

});```
````